# Inserting Grid of buttons on meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I just recently started to use meteor trying to figure out how to make things work on it. I've been working on this for a couple of days. I'm reading discover meteor and trying to figure out how templates work. What am I doing wrong here? How do I get my buttons grid to appear?

JS/jQuery:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.bubbles.grid = function () {

    var el;
    for(var i=1; i<=64; i++){
       return el = document.createElement('div');
        $(el).addClass('button');
        $(el).on('click', function(){
            $(this).addClass('removed');
        });
        $('#container').append(el);
    }
  };

  Template.hello.events({
    'click input' : function () {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
        console.log("You pressed the button");
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {

  });
}
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 440px;
    max-width: 440px;
}
#container > .button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/50x50');
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    opacity: 0.85;
    transition: all 0.07s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.07s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.07s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#container > .button:hover {
    opacity: 1;    
}
#container > .button.removed {
    background-image: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>bubblepopper</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>
<template name ="grid">
  <div id="container"></div>

</template>
<template name="hello">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  {{> grid}}

</template>
```

Definitely something very new and challenging for me am I on the right track? What do I need to do to make my grid appear and also will the grid be updated on the meteor server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that you are doing something wrong when you are manually creating DOM elements. That's not the template way of doing things and definitely not the meteor way either. You also have some general javascript errors in your code ("return el .."?)

Try something like this instead (untested):

```
<template name ="grid">
  {{#each buttons}}
    <div class='button'>button {{value}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

And:

```
Template.grid.buttons = function () {
    var list = [];
    for(var i=1; i<=64; i++){
       list.push({value: i});
    }
    return list;
};

Template.grid.events({
   'click .button': function(ev) {
         $(ev.target).addClass('removed');
   }
});
```

Comment: Alright @christianf put this in my if(Meteor.isClient) spot and it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: thanks for serial downvoting me! Your code is not helpful at all and I'm going to figure it out by myself thanks for all your hard work though!

Comment: I have only downvoted you once, and I left a text explaining it. So don't claim otherwise. Again, if you don't want help then don't come here.

Comment: Be more specific than "doesn't seem to work".  Are you getting an error?